# How to abort component render based on a condition

Tags: extjs, event-handling

Using ExtJS, how to prevent a component from being rendered into DOM based on a condition? The code would probably be something like this (I'm using Sencha Architect to generate the code, so I'm not 100% familiar with the syntax)

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyButton', {
    extend: 'Ext.button.Button',

    text: 'MyButton',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            listeners: {
                beforerender: {
                    fn: me.onButtonBeforeRender,
                    scope: me
                }
            }
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    },

    onButtonBeforeRender: function(component, eOpts) {
        if (MyCondition) {
            // all good, go on with rendering this component
        }
        else {
            // no good, abort, this component should not be rendered
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just return `false` to stop the rendering of the component. Check the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-event-beforerender).

So maybe your function would look something like this:

```
onButtonBeforeRender: function(component, eOpts) {
    if (MyCondition) {
        // all good, go on with rendering this component
        return true;
    }
    else {
        // no good, abort, this component should not be rendered
        return false;
    }
}
```